# How to connect specify table name in oracle SQL with dropwizard application?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, dropwizard

I am not able to connect oracle SQL with dropwizard application. Below is my config

```
oracleDataSource:
  driverClass: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  user: root
  password: 123
  url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//194.18.4.101:1521/serviceName123
  properties:
    charSet: UTF-8
    hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    hibernate.show_sql: true
    hibernate.current_session_context_class: org.hibernate.context.internal.ManagedSessionContext
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: none
    hibernate.jdbc.batch_size: 20
  maxWaitForConnection: 1s
  minSize: 1
  initialSize: 4
  maxSize: 5
  checkConnectionWhileIdle: true
  validationInterval: 10s
  minIdleTime: 1 minute
  validationQuery: SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
```

validationQuery is failing as its not able to get table name. how do I specify tableName in config?

Comment: You parameters look fine as far as I can tell. `DUAL` is the table name. It is a public pseudo-table available to all users. What specific error is being returned?

Comment: @pmdba my validationQuery was getting overridden in code, due to that it was picking different validationQuery.